# How to make some selected countries in the same color?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, colors, region

Here is a good example of world map. I want to divide it into some regions, like Asia, Europe and so onn to make the countries in one region in the same color. How to make it? http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-world-map-colors-tooltips.html

I also want to add some values in every region, like the region name. How to do it?

Comment: Have you looked the source code for that website? Brilliant really, the SVG holds the country name and area mapping. So all JavaScript does is color in the SVG and show the attribute title as an overlay. The problem is that there's no definition of any "regions", check out the SVG, there's only country definitions. Either get a svg that only shows continents, or define which countries are part of the same region.